# Fork and Waitpid calls in a CTF linux binary

Tags: linux, anti-debugging

I'm doing one of my first linux crackmes.

In the first blocks of code, it goes inside some anti-debug routine and inside one of those it **forks** and after it calls a **waitpid** routine. I can verify it and understand purely the code but I can't get why the creators put this code and how it can be an anti-debug technique. These are the interesting blocks.

[image: Fork and Waitpid calls]

Comment: This is impossible to tell if you don't show the rest of the code. There are lot of ways to implement an anti-debugger with a sub-process.

Comment: Since it will be no-readable to screenshot other blocks of code, this is the executable I'm trying to analyze: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oagp3scl54btob/reverse_me?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the process calls `fork`, on the child side it'll try to attach a debugger to the parent process:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, getppid(), 0, 0);
```

If this syscall failed, it probably means a debugger is already attached to the parent process, this is your anti-debugger. To notify the parent process, the developer relies on the exit code. It's 1 if a debugger is attached, 0 otherwise.

On the parent side, it retrieves the exit code with the macro `WEXITSTATUS`. In C this is defined as:

```
#define WEXITSTATUS(x)  (_W_INT(x) >> 8)
```

Which gives in assembly:

```
sar     eax, 8
movzx   eax, al
test    eax, eax
jz      short no_debugger
```

This is another way to do a `PTRACE_TRACEME`. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation. May I continue to ask your help in some other parts of this executable that are behind my actual comprehension? Do I need to open other threads?

Comment: Sure and it's up to you about creating another threads

Comment: I was thinking, why you said that on the child side it'll try to attach a debugger to the parent process? After the fork(), if the JNZ instruction is false I would be into the child process, and the getpid() call would return the PID of the child, why the PID of the parent process? What am I missing?

Comment: The exectuable uses ``getppid``(note the extra 'p') not ``getpid``.  The first function returns the PID of the parent process where the latter returns the current PID.

Comment: OMG, how I missed it...sorry for the dumb question. -_-

Comment: This is fine, no worries. :)